# using :contains selector with variable

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use the :contains selector with a variable but it doesn't seem to want to take in the variable.

```
$('td:contains('" + value + "')').closest('tr').css('background-color','red');
```

All im trying to do is looping through all the td's with a .each function and within that im checking if the td contains the value variable, then set the closest tr background to red or add a class or what ever.

Am I missing something obvious here? I'm partially thinking it is to do with placement of quotation marks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to learn how to escape variables into strings. Your solution

```
 $('td:contains("' + value + '")').closest('tr').css('background-color','red');
```

See the reversed quotes.

In ES2015 (either when directly supported by enough browsers, or if you're transpiling) you could use a *template* literal instead, quoted with backticks, referring to the variable (or any other expression) using `${...}`:

```
 $(`td:contains("${value}")`).closest('tr').css('background-color','red');
```

Comment: perfect thanks! So it was just my ' " being the wrong way round! Ill accept as soon as timer is up.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude that needs , `backtick` ` and you overrode the TJ's changes.

Comment: I rollback it. I didn't know that kind of syntax, and I think that's a mistake, sorry.

Comment: Don't be but great answer.

Answer (score 2):

Although there is an answer already been posted, another option is to use `.filter()` method:

```
$('td').filter(function(){
   return $(this).text().indexOf(value) != -1;
}).closest('tr').css('background-color','red');
```